# Is it possible to have git gui / gitk look good on a retina Macbook Pro?

Tags: macos, git, macbook-pro-retina, git-gui

I really love git gui and gitk. They work very well for me and I know exactly how to use them. Sadly, they look really pixelated and ugly on my retina macbook. Since it's just text and chrome it would seem on the outset a fairly simple thing to fix. But I've looked around quite a bit for a solution and I haven't found one.

[image: Horrible pixelation]

Comment: By pixelated and ugly, do you mean that there is no font anti-aliasing? I've never seen this application before. Is it based on TK or GTK+ ?

Comment: No. As you can see there is a lot of anti-aliasing going on. I think you have to open up the image in full resolution to appreciate the horror. The application is apparently a Tcl/Tk application.

Comment: You can post the update and accepted it as an answer. Also, out of curiosity, could you post an image of the program with the font fix applied?

Comment: Done and done. Again, you probably have to open up the image in a separate tab to see it. When shown inline in the thread, it's hard to see the problem.

Comment: If you are open to alternatives, I'd suggest SourceTree. It is free and looks great on high res screens. http://www.sourcetreeapp.com

Comment: Can you add a link to a description, how you managed to install git-gui and gitk on OSX? My git on OSX does not come with git-gui and gitk.

Comment: Right, Apple removed these tools from their version of git. I installed git using homebrew: `brew install git`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update August 28, 2013: The [pull request I submitted](http://repo.or.cz/w/git-gui.git/commitdiff/317797bce44f57b0fcdb735a42a6340de09b4257) has been accepted, so I expect the problem will be fixed at the source, hopefully in release 1.9. If you can't wait, follow the work-around presented below.

1. Open your terminal and navigate to `/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Version/8.5/Resources/`
2. Use an editor to open the `Info.plist` file inside the `Wish.app` folder (I used `sudo emacs Wish.app/Contents/Info.plist`)
3. Add the following two lines to the file, before `</dict>` and save it:
     `<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>

     <true/>`
4. Make the OS reload the info file. This can be achieved with these commands:
   `sudo cp -R Wish.app WishCopy.app

   sudo mv Wish.app WishOriginal.app

   sudo mv WishCopy.app Wish.app`
5. Try running `open Wish.app` to see if it worked. If it did, it should work for gitk as well.
6. Do the same thing for git gui, but this time do it on the `Git Gui.app` (mine was in `/usr/local/git/share/git-gui/lib/`)

Oh, and I should probably mention that I found out about the NSHighResolutionCapable key from the tcl-mac mail-list, specifically from [an e-mail by Kevin Walzer](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.tcl.mac/7164).

Here is a screenshot of the nice crisp fonts:
[image: Nice crisp fonts]

Comment: A friend and I had a bit of disagreement about a "blurry font" in another application. I said that the font looked alright (similar to the first image) while he insisted that it was subpar. I see what he meant now.

Comment: Thanks, I did `find the.app -print0 | sudo xargs -0 touch` instead of moving around and it worked for Wish. Though for `git gui` I had to go to finder's `Get Info` and toggle `open in low resolution`.

Answer (score 14):

You can also use Retinizer which I guess will edit the Info.plist for you.

https://sites.google.com/a/mikelpr.com/retinizer/

```
open /System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/
```

Drag&drop Wish into Retinizer. Retinize. Voilà !

Comment: If homebrew caskroom is installed then: `brew cask install retinizer`

Comment: does not work, do I need to reboot?

Answer (score 10):

The solution pointed by @patrick-browne works like a charm and it is simpler, in fact, given that I already did the another approach pointed by @pius too.

As @joe said, just install retinizer with brew cask, then drag Wish and drop into Retinizer:

1. `$ brew cask install retinizer`
2. `$ open /System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/`
3. Drag Wish and drop into Retinizer

Comment: Worked! ... even if I was hoping for a less hacky solution.